# Why centering the div with translateY works on desktop browsers, not on iOS Safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I'm using method described here: http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center to vertically center div.

My code looks like this:

```
.center-helper {

  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This method is working fine on desktop, but not on iOS devices. However, if I change the position to absolute, it's working on iOS Safari. What explains this behavior and which way is proper to vertically center the div?

Comment: The demo code on the link you gave seems to work fine in Mobile Safari. Could you put your code in a fiddle or something? Perhaps something else on your page is interfering with the vertical centering.

Comment: The only place this this does not work is in iOS Cordova (PhoneGap). @BenDyer I would also like and explanation why.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the answer to this problem just today! It's so simple too.  Try this!

```
.center-helper {

  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform:translateY(-50%);
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

The key here is **vertical-align:top;**  This doesn't cause any issues on other browsers and seems to fix the way translateY works on mobile safari! I hope this helps.

For generically vertically centering everything I put it altogether like this.

```
.vertical-align{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Then you can call that on any HTML element to vertical center it even on Mobile Safari! & Mobile Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be the use of % values doesn't always work in iOS devices.

Instead of using % values, I used the viewpoint values and it worked like a charm.

My implementation would be

```
.center-helper {

  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 0;
  translateY(-50%);

}
```

Comment: As far as I know iOS devices have history of problems with vh values when changing the device orientations.

Answer (score -2):

You can use calc like this

```
top: calc(50%-half of the div)
```

if div height is 200px

```
top: calc(50%-100px);
```